# Java Create File and Directory if needed

Tags: java, file

I want to create a file (outside of the workspace) so that everyone who opens my program has his own Textfile.

Currently I have to following Code:

```
private static final File m_dataFile = new File("C:\\temp\\MainPlayersLoginData.txt");
private static FileWriter writer;
private static Scanner reader;

public static void setMainPlayersLoginData(String name, String password) {
    try {
        if (!m_dataFile.exists()) {
            createDirectory();
        }
        writer = new FileWriter(m_dataFile);
        writer.write(name + "\n" + password);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void createDirectory() {
    System.out.println("creating directory: " + m_dataFile.getName());
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        m_dataFile.mkdirs();
        result = true;
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
    }
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("DIR created");
    }
}
```

With this code, the program creates a folder temp as planned, but creates a folder named "MainPlayersLoginData.txt" in it instead of a textfile. In addition I get a FileNotFoundException with the message "Access denied" when initialising the FileWriter.

I tried using m_datafile.mkdir() instead of m_datafile.mkdirs() but this time I get a FileNotFoundException with the message "The system cannot find the specified path" and the folder temp isnt created.

Edit: If i create the folder and the Textfile on my own, everything works fine.

Comment: You're creating the entire path as a directory, Try `m_dataFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`. And set `result` to its return value, not to `true`. It doesn't throw exceptions, unless you have a `securityManager` installed.